# is there anyway to receive message from Twilio and process it in a separate function (not in the Flask)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am building a simple app, where a user can text me any question and I would return the categories of the question via twilio. I got a sample code from Twilio and modified only a little bit for this purpose:

```
    @app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def sms_ahoy_reply():
        resp = MessagingResponse()
        respond_message = request.values.get('Body', None)
        message_status = request.values.get('MessageStatus', None)
        from_number = request.values.get('From')
        to_number = request.values.get('To')
        resp.message(input_msg)
        cat_question=find_categories(input_msg)
        print ("The input msg category is ", cat_question)
    return str(resp)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

The problem is that find_categories is a very big and inefficient function. It takes more than 30 seconds to find the right categories. As a result, I am receiving a 502 error from twilio because twilio is not receiving a valid respond from my code within 30 seconds. I am not sure what kind of respond twilio is expecting from my server.

As a potential solution, I decided to separate these two functions. One function is to receive the message from twilio and give twilio a respond (not sure what kind of responds twilio is looking for). The messages and all its properties, including from number and to number and timestamps would then be passed as parameters into the main function and do further processing. Here is the sample code:

```
def sms_ahoy_reply():
    global respond_message
    global from_number
    global to_number   
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    respond_message = request.values.get('Body', None)
    message_status = request.values.get('MessageStatus', None)
    from_number = request.values.get('From')
    to_number = request.values.get('To')
    resp.message(respond_message)
    return str(resp)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def procedure_function():
    sms_ahoy_reply()
    global respond_message
    global from_number
    global to_number 
    cat_question=find_categories(respond_message)
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, it gives me the 11200 Twilio Application error. In addition, I also got this error

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Comment: You would need some kind of message queue to buffer incomming message and answer later. Take a look at RabbitMQ it is quiet easy to use and have a lot of code example using Python.

Answer (score 0):

SMS is stateless, so you can quickly return empty TwiML to Twilio upon receipt of the webhook on the inbound SMS (since Twilio will wait up to 15 seconds for a reply) and when your function completes, use the Twilio REST API messages resource to send an outbound SMS with the category.

TwiML for Programmable SMS
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml

Send SMS Messages
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I return an empty TwiML? Sorry i am very new to this.. I am currently just returning at the end of the function

Comment: I just tried your suggestions (to my best extend and edit the code above, it doesnt seem to work at all. Still going back to the old HTTP Retrieve error

Comment: Just return resp without setting any values will return empty TwiML. Specific to the Python question and async operations, I don't have that answer.